# How to change button order in video.js (5.0.0-rc52)?

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

I'm trying to change the display order in a video.js skin I'm creating. I get all the CSS/LESS stuff (I think), but I got one problem which I'd like to not solve via CSS.

I want the total duration to appear at the very right of the screen. Sadly, the volume button is rendered before, so I can't use `float:right;` for this.

Is there some API function I missed or some other way to change the order of the buttons?

Thanks

Comment: You sure you cannot use `float: right;`? Messing around with the CSS in Chrome Dev Tools allows me to move it all the way to the right with the default implementation by changing `float: left;` to `float: right` in '.vjs-default-skin .vjs-duration {}`.

Comment: Sadly, thats not an option. On the video.js-page, that works because the volume-button is placed in the DOM **after** the duration. I am currently developing on video.js 5.0.0-rc52 (sorry, forgot to mention it) and the volume-button is now placed in the DOM **before** the duration. So `float:right` does what it's supposed to do, but the duration is still further to the right. Is there any API hook where I could change this order? Or some CSS trick I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, just in case someone gets stuck like I did. I found the solution. :-)

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/1070